# For $a\in\mathbb{R}$, let $f_a:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, f_a(x) = \int_{-x}^x \frac{e^t\cdot\cos(at)}{1+e^t}dt$, determine $\lim_{a\to0}f_a(x)$.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

> For $a\in\mathbb{R}$, let $$f_a:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, f_a(x) = \int_{-x}^x \frac{e^t\cdot\cos(at)}{1+e^t}dt,$$ and $L=\lim_{a\to0}f_a(x)$. Calculate $L$.

I am completely lost with this problem. My instinctive idea is to simply commute the limit with the integral such that $\cos(at)$ becomes $1$, and, although this leads me to the correct answer ($L=\ln(\frac{1+e^x}{1+e^{-x}})$), I know such commutations rarely work and this just so happens to work too.

My questions would be, what would be another way to solve this problem that is rigorous? And if commuting the limit with the integral is correct, what explains that I'm allowed to do that? I've heard of the dominated convergence theorem and the monotone convergence theorem, but we have not studied them in class, and this task (theoretically) should not use them. However, if the solution using those turns out to be simpler, I would highly appreciate if you could explain it!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Do you need DCT for a bounded integrand on a finite interval?

Comment: Hint (although @AaronHendrickson beat me to it): pretty much every justification of commuting a limit operator with an integration operator uses [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).

Comment: Note that your integrand is a smooth function over $\mathbb{R}$ and hence continuous. Thus it has a finite maximal value over the compact set $[-x, x]$ and hence you can take a dominating function such as $C\chi_{\{[-x, x]\}}(t)$ for some suitable $C\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$0\le \int\limits_{-x}^x{e^t\over e^t+1}\,dt-\int\limits_{-x}^x{e^t\cos(at)\over e^t+1}\,dt=2\int\limits_{-x}^x{e^t\sin^2(at/2)\over e^t+1}\,dt\le {a^2\over 2}\int\limits_{-x}^x{t^2e^t\over e^t+1}\,dt$$ On the way we have applied the inequality  $|\sin u|\le |u|.$ Therefore
the limit of the difference is equal $0.$ Hence
$$\lim_{a\to 0}\int\limits_{-x}^x{e^t\cos(at)\over e^t+1}\,dt=\int\limits_{-x}^x{e^t\over e^t+1}\,dt=\ln\left ({1+e^x\over 1+e^{-x}}\right )=x$$**Remark** It can be shown that for $a\neq 0$ we have$$\int\limits_{-x}^x{e^t\cos(at)\over e^t+1}\,dt={\sin(ax)\over a} $$ hence the limit is equal $x.$